# Swift: Timer firing late when running in background

Tags: ios, swift, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I have a music app that plays audio in the background. I'm trying to implement a sleep feature to stop the audio after a set amount of time.

I've created a timer:

```
 sleepTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: sleepInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(stopMusic), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

The timer works fine if the app is open but triggers late if the app is running in the background. The amount of time it's late varies but it can be up to twice as long as the original interval.

I've tried using DispatchSourceTimer and asyncAfter and they both have the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+timer+background).

Comment: Unfortunately none of those answers explain my situation.

Comment: make invalidate timer and reschedule that timer again with same time interval while your app going to the background.